# INVOKE MASM saving registers automatically?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

Is it possible to save cpu registers automatically when I use the Invoke directive in masm?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the example I posted there: [selection sort in assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020853/selection-sort-in-assembly-language/4031060#4031060)

The USES directive in the target PROC is what you are looking for.
USES EAX ESI EDI will automatically save those registers upon PROC entry and restore them upon exit (even if you have multiple RET points, and even if having multiple ret points is not recommended). IOW, it will generate PUSHes upon PROC entry and consistently matched (reverse order) POPs before each and every RET. The idea is that since this is assembly, you have full control and responsability upon those registers you modify **and** want to preserve.
And contrary to what was suggested somewhere else, declaring stdcall doesn't preserve anything automatically for you in MASM. It just determines whether the caller (code generated for INVOKE) or the callee (code generated in the PROC) POPs the parms.

Comment: This question is about `invoke`, not `proc`. Or you mean that you can use `uses` with `invoke`?

Comment: The only use of INVOKE is to call a PROC with call convention, parms, etc.

Comment: INVOKE is a HLL wrapper around call, handling call convention, parms, etc. INVOKE and PROC extensions are the two sides of the same coin. For instance, according to the proc type, the parms will be removed by the caller (upon return, thus generated by the INVOKE) or the callee (inside the proc just before each RET). There is and can't be no other way to automatically save / restore regs in MASM but this one. Otherwise, it's manually, for each and every call, by PUSHing before the invoke and POPping on return.

Comment: @filofel: "The only use of INVOKE is to call a PROC" - really? what about imported functions calls? I can write `invoke GetCommandLine`, where is `proc`? What will preserve my registers?

Comment: @abyx: Well, sure. My understanding was that we were talking pure assembly here. And PROC is the masm way of defining an stdcall or cdecl function. If you INVOKE GetCommandLine(), GetCommandLine will preserve your registers. While PROC will only preserve what you explicitly tell it you USES. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: @filofel: GetCommandLine will not preserve ecx and edx. How to do save them automatically?

Comment: @abyx: There is no builtin way to do this "automatically" at the calling point. The only ways ways are to push / pop registers around the call, either directly, or through a macro, or by calling a wrapper fnc that will do it then call the GetCommandLine(), but those are by no way "automatic".  The point is that the general way of preserving registers is inside the callee rather than from the caller, if only so that the saving / restoring instructions exist once in the function rather than at each and every call point (which is a reason to use stdcall, that's better than cdecl for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

"stdcall" calling convention guarantees that function won't spoil any registers but eax, edx, ecx. If you want to save edx and ecx - write a macro.

Comment: Is there any way I can force eax to be auto-saved and then auto-restored during an INVOKE?

Comment: @Jumbo you can write macro to save it, but when you will restore it you will loose function return value.

Comment: stdcall doesn't garantee anything in MASM, in fact. It might at best suggest that the function should behave this way. To have registers automagically saved / restored, you have to use the USES directive in the PROC definition. See my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you meant, and since your tag is masm32 I'll assume Windows x86.

What is perfectly possible is to push all the arguments that an API call requires and then you just call the desired function. What I mean is that when you're promming in assembly for Windows you don't need to use registers to "invoke" the APIs, you have to push the arguments and then call (or invoke) the API.

For example, this:

```
push 0
push DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
push 0
push 0
push 80000000h
push 80000000h
push 80000000h
push 80000000h
push 0CF0000h
push offset AppName
push offset ClassName
push 0h
call CreateWindowExA
```

is exactly equal to this (in fact just the values of the parameters are different):

```
invoke CreateWindowEx,NULL,ADDR ClassName,ADDR AppName,\
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT,\
       CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,CW_USEDEFAULT,NULL,NULL,\
       hInst,NULL
```

Is that what you meant with your question?